# Score Error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

Here's my code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

california_housing = fetch_california_housing(as_frame=True)
data = california_housing.frame

X = data.drop(columns=['MedHouseVal'])
y = data['MedHouseVal']

model = LinearRegression()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)  

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
model.score(predictions, y_test)
```

Here's the error message:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0.71912284
1.76401657 2.70965883 ... 4.46877017 1.18751119 2.00940251]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[`score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score) needs to be called on the testing features and not output:

```py
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.score(X_test, y_test)
```